# Hitting 99% memory in Spyder / iPython and then entire computer freezes

Tags: python, linux, spyder

This might be a linux specific quesion, so if so. I run Ubuntu 18.x. I use spyder daily for data analysis, working with large datasets. Often, I will overload memory and python will automatically restart the ipython console, or crash with a memory overload warning. Sometimes in spyder though, it just locks up at 99% memory and I need to force shutdown. This gets quite frustrating.

Wondering if there is any small scripts I can use to automatically kill the ipython console at say 98% memory, or somehow avoid complete lock up?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into any of the notebook settings that you can declare inline? I believe you can specifcy how much memory, etc. is dedicated to the ipython.  That being said, this may help, but the data may still require greater resources

Comment: having the same problem too, atmospheric scientist